# SSRS Expression to Populate Parameter Dropdown Based on Date

Tags: sql-server-2012, expression, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I'm currently struggling with how to produce a Fiscal Year parameter, so its values start with Current year, but also contain records from all previous years, and then have all following values be each following year.

So the Fiscal Year would look roughly like the following

Current (I would want to include all previous Fiscal years in this as well), 
F18, 
F19, 
F20, 
etc. etc.

As of right now, I have all fiscal years on the drop down, starting with the earliest fiscal year that exists in the database using the following query to populate the parameter dropdown.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FiscalConsideration FROM dbo.Currency
```

Which would look like this

F12, 
F14, 
F15, 
F16, 
F17, 
F18, 
etc. etc.

Then I filter the results based on the selected Fiscal year.

**Question 1**
Is there a way where I might be able to do this, have all records from current fiscal year and prior on one value and all individual fiscal years after?

**Question 2**
I have also discovered that I can't have this be multi-select AND accept NULL's as well.  Might I be able to convert nulls to a custom string or something and have that be an option as well?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it by incorporating more of the logic I wanted into the computed column in SQL Server Management Studio with another case when for past records, and changing nulls with isnull to 'TBD'